# Eclipse plugin fragment dependency

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse applications with some framents to test the plugin functionality.

Now I need to develop some utility classes, to be used across fragmens, **just for the sake of testing.**

So I need a plugin (or fragment) to be included ONLY in fragment (is it possible??) to use these utilities..
What's the best way to have such a structure?

(These utilities should not be included in production plugins nor be deployed in production)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a regular plugin for your utility classes and add it as dependency of your test fragments. Using a fragment for utility classes doesn't sound right - what would the host bundle of that fragment be?

> These utilities should not be included in production plugins nor be deployed in production

I would assume your test fragments are already excluded from being deployed to production. You should be able to configure everything in a similar way to exclude the utility plugin. How to do that exactly depends on your project setup.

---

Update for the situation described in the comments:

If some tests from fragments must use a utility plugin which requires dependencies to multiple host plugins, then it means these tests are some kind of integration tests.

Test fragments are useful for unit tests to test internal classes but are not really suitable for integration tests because they easily cause dependencies issues like you have now.

These kind of tests should be moved to their own plugin (I usually have a single integration test plugin for the whole application which also contains test utilities). Then this integration test plugin can depend on everything it requires without conflicts.

Comment: This is what I did. But I have a circular dependency. Let's make an example:

Plugin A is my main plugin to test. FA is the plugin fragment. U is the utility plugin. 
FA includes U to use the utilities.
BUT U includes A as dependency (since I need some data classes from A).

This setup **compiles**, but when I build the feature I get an error with a circular dependency. Only when I build a feature....

Comment: Ok that makes everything a bit more complicated. I assume U also depends on data classes of other plugins like plugin B? In this case I would first check if it would be possible to remove all dependencies to these data classes from U, e.g. by moving utility classes/methods that use classes from by A into FA, from B into FB etc., so that U contains only generic utilities shared by all fragments.

Comment: Another approach here would be to move all data classes from A, B etc into new plugins (DA, DB). If you let U only depend on DA, then FA can depend on U without circular dependencies. If you still have circular dependencies (because e.g. B depends on A) then you might need to split U into separate plugins (lets call them UA, UB etc.) This could be a lot work though, so I would probably try the first approach first.

Comment: The problem is with data types, that are in plugin A and used across all application plugins. I can't move those classes.

Maybe using Maven/Tycho as build system would "fix" the problem.
Now the workaround is simple... Just close the U plugin in Eclipse.... The fragments don't build.. but they are not included in product export!

Comment: Tycho is a good choice and way better than Eclipse exports but I don't think it will help with this issue. Even if it builds, you probably get circular dependency errors at runtime. I think the first approach (moving utility methods/classes that use data types to the respective plugin's fragment) is the easiest solution then.

Comment: I don't think I can do that, since plugin U also runs some code that must be run before each test (sorry I didn't mention before).
So it just holds a piece of code that should be in any fragment, but I don't want it to duplicated.
This code uses data types, from plugin A and B.

Anyway I don't get any circular dependency errors at runtime.

Comment: Ok then it wouldn't work like this. I've updated the answer with another solution

Comment: OK, but I have many fragments plugins, each of which tests the host plugin functionality. This is how is organized now, to follow your solution I should make may changes... 

The integration test plugin is a normal plugin not a fragment right?

Comment: Right, it should be a normal plugin. But just to be clear, you don't have to move all tests to that plugin. If you have unit test that really just depend on the host plugin then those test should probably stay in a fragment.

Comment: OK, that is my situation.. I have unit test that just depend on the host plugin.. but they share common code.. I think I will have to change my test "suite" completely.. reorganizing things..